# Set to NA if the value outside the range

Tags: r

My data set contains 6 fields and four rows with some NA values.

```
a=c(5,6,7,12)
b=c(7,2,3,4)
c=c(8,8,21)
d=c(1,1)
e=c(1,2,5,9)
f=c(20,3,11)
length(c)=4
length(d)=4
length(f)=4
z=data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)


a   b   c   d   e   f
5   7   8   1   1   20
6   2   8   1   2   3
7   3   21  NA  5   11
12  4   NA  NA  9   NA
```

This is what I need to do: for the fields a, c, d, and f if the value less than 6 or greater than 12, then I need
to set it to NA. Also, if the value is alread NA then no change (keep it NA).

I can use ifelse for each field to do that, but my data contains tens of fields so I was wondering if there is an efficient
way to do that.

The final data is

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
NA  7   8   NA  1   NA
6   2   8   NA  2   NA
7   3   NA  NA  5   11
12  4   NA  NA  9   NA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the column index ('v1'), we subset the dataset 'z', change the elements that are TRUE based on the logical condition to `NA` by `is.na`.

```
v1 <- c('a', 'c', 'd', 'f')
is.na(z[v1]) <-  z[v1] < 6 | z[v1] >12
z
#   a b  c  d e  f
#1 NA 7  8 NA 1 NA
#2  6 2  8 NA 2 NA
#3  7 3 NA NA 5 11
#4 12 4 NA NA 9 NA
```

Or a faster approach as suggested by @DavidArenburg is

```
z[v1][z[v1] < 6 | z[v1] > 12] <- NA
```

---

Or a data.table option by @DavidArenburg.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(z)`), loop through the columns specified in 'v1' and `set` the elements that meets the condition to `NA`.  This would be much faster as the overhead in `[.data.table` is avoided.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(z)
for(j in v1){
   set(z, i = which(z[[j]] < 6 | z[[j]] > 12), j = j, value = NA_integer_)
}

z
#   a b  c  d e  f
#1: NA 7  8 NA 1 NA
#2:  6 2  8 NA 2 NA
#3:  7 3 NA NA 5 11
#4: 12 4 NA NA 9 NA
```

Comment: Or `z[indx][z[indx] < 6 | z[indx] > 12] <- NA`, smells like a dupe to me

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, it could be.  Free feel to close it if you find a dupe.

Comment: And this one too if you already at it `library(data.table) ; for(j in indx) set(z, i = which(z[[j]] < 6 | z[[j]] > 12), j = j, value = NA_integer_)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't think about data.table.  The `set` would be much faster

Comment: Thank you all. This was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative which I feel simplifies the syntax a little without costing too much in speed:

```
z[v1] <- replace(z, z < 6 | z > 12, NA)[v1]
```

A more efficient variation suggested by @akrun is to use `lapply` in combination with `replace`:

```
z[v1] <- lapply(z[v1], function(x) replace(x, x < 6 | x > 12, NA)
```

Some benchmarking using 5000 columns, 10000 rows and 2500 variables to replace across seems to suggest this is not going to break the bank in most circumstances, and that the `lapply` solution is very competitive to other packages like `data.table`:

```
set.seed(1)
z <- setNames(
  data.frame(
    replicate(5000, sample(1:20,10000,replace=TRUE), simplify=FALSE)),
   paste0("a",1:5000))
v1 <- sample(colnames(z), 2500)


system.time(z[v1] <- replace(z, z < 6 | z > 12, NA)[v1])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   6.17    0.00    6.16 

system.time(z[v1] <- lapply(z[v1], function(x) replace(x, x < 6 | x > 12, NA)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.14    0.00    1.13

system.time(is.na(z[v1]) <-  z[v1] < 6 | z[v1] >12)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.53    0.00    2.53 

system.time(z[v1][z[v1] < 6 | z[v1] > 12] <- NA)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.55    0.00    2.54 

library(data.table)
setDT(z)
system.time(
for(j in v1){
   set(z, i = which(z[[j]] < 6 | z[[j]] > 12), j = j, value = NA_integer_)
}
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.03    0.00    1.03
```

Comment: Wrapping with `which` in `replace` may further increase the speed.

Comment: @akrun - nope, it breaks the code when using `replace` with a `data.frame`

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it.  It must be after matrix conversion.

Comment: @akrun - `which` means the indexes get used as column indexes, e.g. -  `replace(z, 1:4, NA)` replaces columns `1:4` with `NA`

Comment: Perhaps for such a big dataset, `z[v1] <- lapply(z[v1], function(x) replace(x, which(x < 6 | x>12), NA)` might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

df = setDT(melt(as.matrix(z)))
dcast(df[df[, .I[(value<6|value>12) & !X2 %in% c('b', 'e')], by = 1:nrow(df)]$V1, 
            value := NA], X1 ~ X2, value.var = "value")[, -1, with = FALSE]

#    a b  c  d e  f
#1: NA 7  8 NA 1 NA
#2:  6 2  8 NA 2 NA
#3:  7 3 NA NA 5 11
#4: 12 4 NA NA 9 NA
```